# Limit while in macro using keyboard Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, do-while, keyboard-events

I am an enthusiast and a beginner in VBA. I'm writing code for a workbook that manages game statistics.

Initially, mark on the court (determined by a range) from where the kick and fate occurred between the beams - Beacon (determined by another range). To do this, I created a macro with the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + X for when it is not a goal, and Ctrl + Shift + O for when it is goal. The macro, for now, adds x + index. This index is taken from the total number of kicks that is stored in a cell that is manipulated manually (for now). That is, if the cell containing TotalShootP1TA (Team 1 player Total Kick) contains the total of 10 kicks in the game, the moment the macro is called, the x10 marker will be added to the active cell. What should happen to the goal macro. For example, in the 11th goal kick, the o11 marker will be inserted into the active cell. As the picture suggests.

[image]

However my problem is that I need to call my macro 2x to register (1) in the block from where the kick was and (2) where it went below the beams.

The consequence of this is to register erroneously as if there were 2x kicks thus increasing the cell NGoalP1TA (Not Goal Player1 TeamA) in 2x, because each time it is called it adds 1:
`Range (" NGoalP1TA ")`. `Value = Range (" NGoalP1TA ")`.

That is, I need a way to register how many times my macro was called. One way I thought of getting around was: performing a conditioned while loop by pressing the keys. For example, as long as you did not press Ctrl + Shift + Q the code would remain in the while. You can like this:

1. Mark inside court.
2. Change the active cell.
3. And then, mark with the same index below the beams.
4. Finally, pressing Ctrl + Shift + Q, the code would go out while raising the variable NGoalP1TA (Not Goal Player1 TeamA) once.

Even reading about the Application.OnKey methods I could not write a functional code.

However, I'm not even sure if that will work out. A simple for has not resolved because it does not allow to change the active cell.

Other suggestions are welcome.

Sketch of the code which I think would work:

```vb
Sub NotGoal()
    ' NotGoal Macro
    ' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+X
    '
    Dim NGoalP1TA As Integer
    Dim TotalShootP1TA As Integer
    DO WHILE CTRL+SHIFT+Q
        If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("CourtP1TA")) Is Nothing Or Not
            Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("BalizaP1TA")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("if Intersect")
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "x" & Range("TotalShootsP1TA").Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("else Intersect!")
        End If
    LOOP
    Range("NGoalP1TA").Value = Range("NGoalP1TA").Value + 1
End Sub
```

Current Code:

```vb
Sub NotGoal()
    ' NotGoal Macro
    ' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+X
    '
    Dim NGoalP1TA As Integer
    Dim TotalShootP1TA As Integer
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("CourtP1TA")) Is Nothing Or Not
        Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("BalizaP1TA")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("if Intersect")
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "x" & Range("TotalShootsP1TA").Value
        Range("NGoalP1TA").Value = Range("NGoalP1TA").Value + 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("else Intersect!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a TL;DR at the top of your question - imagine addressing a somewhat busy co-worker, not a fellow enthusiast. Have you seen [How to ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sure.. but, who TL;DR?